# Expansion files at Android 6

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions, apk-expansion-files

On Android 6 devices, we've noticed that expansion files now need that we request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission at runtime, which allows the user to deny, which doesn't allow us to continue with the app startup.

Is there a way to prevent the expansion files to use the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or to prevent the user of denying?

If that request must appear when using expansion files, how are we supposed to handle that gracefully?

Comment: Explain to the user that your app does not work without that permission, and then request it again.

Comment: That's not possible, specially if they choose to never be asked about that again

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. To resolve it for API 23 I download .obb file to private app's file directory instead of `obb` directory which my app hasn't access to. You can review my solution [here](https://github.com/danikula/Google-Play-Expansion-File/commit/93a03bd34acad67c6ea34cfb6c3f02c93bdcea85) .
Usage:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/alexeydanilov/apk-expansion' }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.danikula.expansion:expansion:VERSION@aar'
    compile 'com.danikula.expansion:license:VERSION@aar'
    compile 'com.danikula.expansion:zip:VERSION@aar'
}
```

See the latest versions [here](https://bintray.com/alexeydanilov/apk-expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug on Android 6.0

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197287